# Navigation in React Native going to wrong page

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am using react-native: 0.61.4.

In app.js I have

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from './pages';
import ProfileScreen from './pages';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen}
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

in pages.js I have

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Main Page',
  };
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text>You are on the main Page</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Profile"
          onPress={() => navigate('Profile')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Profile',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text>You are on the profile page</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

On the IOS simulator, the app loads properly and shows HomeScreen.  When clicking on the button though, instead of taking me to ProfileScreen like it should, it looks like it moves forward in the stack to an identical page of HomeScreen, except the page has a back button that goes back to the actual HomeScreen.  Anyone know what is wrong with my navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a default export in your pages.js instead of just export HomeScreen as default switch it to:

```js
export { HomeScreen, ProfileScreen };
```

So you have access to both in app.js, and import them as

```js
import { HomeScreen, ProfileScreen } from './pages';
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure I'm following what you're saying to do in pages.js.   Are you saying to remove the `export default` from `HomeScreen` and add `export default { HomeScreen, ProfileScreen };` after the classes?

Comment: Yes, what you are doing is exporting homescreen only so when you import it in app.js with this: import HomeScreen from './pages';
import ProfileScreen from './pages';  what you are actualy doing is import two instances of HomeScreen just with different name

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I get an error: `Error: The component for route 'Home' must be a React Component.`

Comment: You are right is without the default, i will update my answer